# Doctrine2 mongodb and Timestamp

Tags: mongodb, doctrine-orm

I use doctrine 2 to write to mongodb and an Entity looks like this :

```
{
  "_id" : ObjectId("54538be2516bd636738b46f2"),
  "department" : "Assistance",
  "action" : "DONE",
  "idAppointment" : 2197,
  "service_order" : "F4889109",
  "access_number" : "164016178",
  "so_type" : "DERA",
  "stage" : "D40",
  "id_va" : "FT452926",
  "id_icms" : "F4889109",
  "ref_isp" : "",
  "comment" : "",
  "first_available_schedule" : Timestamp(1414623600, 168),
  "asap" : false,
  "allday" : "NO",
  "operator" : "HD8",
  "created" : Timestamp(1414761442, 169)
}
```

Now I want to make a query on the timestamp either with querybuilder or on the command line but I don't know exactly  how to do this. Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For starters, you appear to be using the [Timestamp](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/bson-types/#timestamps) BSON type when you should actually be using the [Date](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/bson-types/#date) type. In ODM, these use the `@Timestamp` and `@Date` annotations, respectively. In the PHP driver, the relevant driver classes are [MongoTimestamp](http://php.net/manual/en/class.mongotimestamp.php) and [MongoDate](http://php.net/manual/en/class.mongodate.php), respectively.

As the BSON documentation link above states, Timestamp is intended for internal use (MongoDB uses it in the replication oplog). If you're storing dates and times in your application, the Date time is certainly what you should use.

Looking at the [`@Timestamp`](http://doctrine-mongodb-odm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/annotations-reference.html#timestamp) example in ODM's documentation, it's rather unfortunate that the example has it on a `$created` field. We would do better to use a less encouraging field name and add a note that users probably don't want to map a field as `@Timestamp`.

If you do have fields mapped as `@Date`, you should be able to use the query builder as you would with any other field and operator (relevant to a date value). When preparing the query, [`DocumentPersister::prepareQueryOrNewObj()`](https://github.com/doctrine/mongodb-odm/blob/29bdaa310f791fc0ec439fe2935348dfce4797c3/lib/Doctrine/ODM/MongoDB/Persisters/DocumentPersister.php#L906) will ultimately run the query value corresponding to a date-mapped field through [`DateType::convertToDatabaseValue()`](https://github.com/doctrine/mongodb-odm/blob/29bdaa310f791fc0ec439fe2935348dfce4797c3/lib/Doctrine/ODM/MongoDB/Types/DateType.php#L31). This means that the value may be an integer timestamp, DateTime, or MongoDate instance. A string would also be suitable, provided it works with `strtotime()`.

Comment: I missed this chapter, so thx a lot. Now I have to update the created field to the date format. How would you suggest doing this? Regards

Comment: This would best be done with a migration script that queries for documents to migrate using the [`$type`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/type/) operator and updates each document. Since the BSON timestamp and date fields are both 64-bit integers, you shouldn't have to worry about the documents growing at all (all updates should be in-place). A PHP CLI script should do the job just fine, and it should be easy to write it in such a way that it can pick up and resume the migration if you terminate it early.